# Eliminar ciertos campos de una tabla de un mismo id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

Tengo dos tablas en la cual quiero eliminar ciertos campos de una tabla relacionada a otra

una tabla se llama procesess y otra diligences y quiero eliminar todos los campos que tengan en status_diligence los valores de: pendiente, rechazado, enviado hay otro valor que es aprobado pero los campos con ese valor deben permanecer

he intentado con esto pero no funciona o me borra todos los que estan con ese id así tenga el valor de aprobado

intento1

```
$diligences = Diligence::where('process_id', "=", $id)->delete([
    ['status_diligence', "=", "pendiente"],
    ['status_diligence', "=", "rechazado"],
    ['status_diligence', "=", "enviado"]
]);
```

intento 2

```
$diligences = Diligence::select('process_id', $id)
                        ->where(function($q) {
                            $q->where('status_diligence', 'pendiente')
                            ->where('status_diligence', 'rechazado')
                            ->where('status_diligence', 'enviado');
                        })
                        ->delete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como deseas eliminar de la entidad `Diligence` basados en un criterio de coincidencia de valores entonces puedes hacer uso del método `whereIn`.

El anterior método te va a pedir:

- Nombre de la columna donde se busca encontrar las coincidencias
- Un array con los valores que esperas encontrar como coincidencias

Entonces tu consulta pudiera quedar así:

```
$eliminados = Diligence::whereIn('status_diligence', ['pendiente', 'rechazado', 'enviado'])
                        ->delete();
```

Ahora si aparte a este filtro necesitas agregarle la llave foránea que es: **`process_id`** solo deberás encadenar un método `where` entre el `whereIn` y el `delete` de esta forma:

Código:

```
$eliminados = Diligence::whereIn('status_diligence', ['pendiente', 'rechazado', 'enviado'])
                        ->whereProcessId($id)
                        ->delete();
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Me podrías explicar como se usa el whereProcessId? no conocía sobre ello.

Comment: Al método `where` le puedes componer el nombre agregando en este mismo el nombre de la columna con la cual deseas buscar la comparación, así por dentro de los paréntesis de este solo pasas el valor a evaluar que en este caso es la variable `id`, solo considera que si por ejemplo al columna es `status` deberá ser con esta sintaxis: `whereStatus` o en el caso de tu ejercicio que esta separado por un guión bajo, en el where lo quitarás y cada una de las palabras empezará en mayúscula.